# CSS select element if parent does not have non-adjacent succeeding sibling element with a given class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following situations:

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="background">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
<div class="indicators"></div>
<div class="overlay">...</div>
<div class="border speaking">
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="background">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
<div class="indicators"></div>
<div class="overlay">...</div>
<div class="border">
```

I would like to select the `background` div in the former example, but not the latter. The only difference between the two is the presence of the `speaking` class on the final div.

I tried `.content:not( ~ .border:not(.speaking) ) > .background`, but this did not work. I am on Firefox Developer Edition, and as such do not currently have access to `:has`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can only do it with has()

Comment: @TemaniAfif why's that?

Comment: Because of the way the global cascade works, you can only go down, not up. Has gives context that wasn't previously available. If you can't use has then you need to use JavaScript.